# loss of const volatile qualifiers

Tags: c++, templates, volatile

I have a compile error:

> ```
> error C3848: expression having type 'const unicode::endian_swap<T>'
>              would lose some const-volatile qualifiers in order to call
>              'unsigned long unicode::endian_swap<T>::operator ()(T &)'
> ```

The description of this error, [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t209x37w%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), doesn't really explain what's going on.

I'm unable to reproduce the error in a smaller sample, but I can show the basic layout of my class.

```
template < typename T >
struct endian_swap
{
    endian_swap ( void ) {}
    T operator () ( T& _val ) const { return _val >> 8 | _val << 8; }
};

template < typename T >
struct test
{
    endian_swap< T > _swap;

    virtual void do_it ( ) const
    {
        unsigned short n = 0x1234;
        unsigned short * _dest = &n;

        *_dest++ = _swap( n ); // <-- Error is here
    }
};
```

The error popped up after adding `endian_swap` as a member. The actual class is derived from `std::codecvt` and installed into an `std::locale`.

Can somebody give a better explanation of the error than the site above.

Edit: Actual code:

```
template < typename T, size_t N = sizeof( T ) > struct endian_swap
{
    endian_swap ( void ) {};
    T operator () ( const T _val ) const { return _val };
};
template < typename T > struct endian_swap< T, 2 >
{
    endian_swap ( void ) {}
    T operator () ( const T _val ) const { return _val >> 8 | _val << 8; }
};
template < typename T > struct endian_swap< T, 4 >
{
    endian_swap ( void ) {};
    T operator () ( const T _val ) const { return (_val >> 24) | ((_val & 0x00ff0000) >> 8) | ((_val & 0x0000ff00) << 8) | (_val << 24) };
};
```

Update:
Found it! Look carefully at the above template and see if you can see it too.

Comment: Your endian swap function doesn't work right if `T` is signed.  Also, there's no good reason to take `_val` by reference.

Comment: +1 for "usually google gives me the answers"!

Comment: @BenVoigt That's by design, all template parameters are forced to unsigned.

Comment: @Waldermort: Still, I disagree with passing `_val` by reference.  And especially a non-`const` reference is a bad idea.

Comment: @BenVoigt This is a minimal example, even though I can't get the error.

Comment: You seem to have undefined behavior an that line, where `n` could be modified twice.  But I doubt that is the cause of the error message (directly).  Are you calling the `do_it` function on a `volatile test` instance?

Comment: @John: `n` isn't modified at all.  And the error message mentions `const` but not `volatile`.

Comment: @Ben `n` is passed into `operator()` of `_swap` by non-const reference, and the return is assigned to `*_dest` which points to `n`.

Comment: @John: Ahh, missed that.  Then it's modified exactly once, by the assignment operator.  After the `operator()()` function call returns, which creates a happens-before relationship (no longer called sequence point, thanks C++11).

Comment: @John The non-const reference probably should be const, because the value isn't modified in the function.

Comment: @James: Really it shouldn't be a reference at all.

Comment: T operator () ( const T _val ) const { return _val >> 8 | _val << 8; } still has the error. Like I said, it's a minimal example.

Comment: I also wonder about using a template at all, since the actual code will work for exactly two types, and no more.

Comment: OK, To all, endian_swap in the example is part of a specialized template where the parameters can only be unsigned.

Comment: @Waldermort: Is the code *inside* `endian_swap<T>::operator()()` the real code, or have you changed that for exposition also?

Comment: No, That code is the specialization for unsigned short, reduced to a single template.

Comment: Is it the real code for `endian_swap<unsigned short>::operator()()` ?

Comment: yes, the only thing changed is the `template <>` to `template <typename T>`

Comment: Then pass by value, not reference.  `T operator()( T _val ) const { return ... `

Comment: Since I can't reproduce the error I have a feeling it's the way it's stored inside the `locale` class.

Comment: Tried it and mentioned it a few lines above.

Comment: @Waldermort: When you post code snippets without code formatting, things disappear.  Angle brackets, pointer asterisks.  So I wasn't trusting that comment.

Comment: Is there any reason for `endian_swap` to be a template, as opposed to an ordinary class with a bunch of overloaded `operator()` functions?

Comment: ha, no worries. `unsigned short x = 1234;unsigned short n = _ByteSwap( x );` inside the actual method also causes the error, so It's not the values either.

Comment: yes, I have specializations for 3 types and a no-op by default. template functor is the best fit.

Comment: @BenVoigt Or even just free functions?

Comment: @Waldermort I can't see the error in the code you post (except for a couple of missing semi-colons).  Nor can my compilers.

Comment: Those misplaced semi-colons were causing the error. My compiler should have caught it but didn't. (VS2010)

Comment: @Waldermort That is weird.  VS2012 compiled it correctly; g++ gave an error "missing semicolon".  In general: VC++ doesn't detect any errors in a template until it is instantiated (and the ones with the missing semicolons weren't instantiated); g++ does.  Which is the phenomenon that I observed (with VC++11 and I forget which version of g++.)

Comment: @JamesKanze VS2012 compiled it with the error? Having second thought about upgrading now. I'm still trying to figure out why, under the hood, it translated it to an `unsigned long`. Because of that miss type, today, I pulled all the keys out of my keyboard and gave it all a good clean.

Comment: @Waldermort The `unsigned long` surprises me too.  But I'm not surprised about the lack of an error with VS2012.  As I said, VC++ doesn't generally do any checking before instantiation.  I'd say that the missing semicolon caused it to miss the end of the previous template, except that when the compiler desynchronizes to that extent, you usually tons of errors later on.  (And if you can, I'd suggest installing CygWin and it's g++.  It may take a little bit of effort, but it's often worth running code through g++ when you have errors, and templates are involved.)

Comment: @JamesKanze nice tip. Though I'll probably install a full linux distro into vmware.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How are you instantiating the template.  Your instantiation of
`endian_swap` uses type `T`, and you pass it an `unsigned
short`.  Unless `T` is `unsigned short`,  you'll need
a conversion, and the results of a conversion are a temporary,
which can't bind to a non-const reference.

You don't provide a SSCCE, so it's hard to say.  But the error
message you post refers to a call to `unsigned long unicode::endian_swap<T>::operator ()(T &);` either
`endian_swap` is instantiated for `unsigned long` (in which
case, passing an `unsigned short` would require a temporary), or
the code you posted is not the code which triggered the error.

Comment: The actual data type is `std::codecvt::intern_type` which is set as `unsigned short` on creation.

Comment: Give me some suggestions to try out. Pulling my hair over this one. :/

Comment: If this is the case then the compiler's diagnostic hopelessly misses the mark.

Comment: @Waldermort If the instantiation type really is an `unsigned short`, then what you've shown should work.  However, the error message says that the return type of your `operator()` is `unsigned long`; the code you posted has it as `T`, so I'm supposing that in fact, you've instantiated on an `unsigned long`.

Comment: `with
1>          [
1>              T=unsigned short
1>          ]` very very sure.

Comment: @Waldermort So post the code which triggers the error, and not something else.  Post a SSCCE, so we can actually see what might be wrong.

Comment: What is SSCCE? As for the actual code, let me edit the question. Wait a few please.

Comment: @Waldermort: It looks like James spotted the problem, it's just the reverse of what he thought.  The template parameter is `unsigned short` but you're passing a parameter of type `unsigned long`.

Comment: The original posted code didn't cause an error, I am unable to reproduce it, as mentioned in the question.

Comment: All the code is posted. As you can see, the `endian_swap` is specialized on `intern_type` and it's size. The type is always unsigned.